# Duplicated inner join results

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, inner-join

With postgres I'm trying to get a single user and all their posts, but when I inner join the Users and Posts tables I receive this:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PhotoPath   | 
Username    | username
Name        | user
Biography   | 
PicturePath | https://gourmetdemexico.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/diferencia-entre-arte-y-cultura-taco-gringo-600x600.jpg
-[ RECORD 2 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PhotoPath   | 
Username    | username
Name        | user
Biography   | 
PicturePath | http://www.travelettes.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mystery2-600x600.jpg
```

QUERY:

```sql
SELECT 
    u."PhotoPath",
    u."Username",
    u."Name",
    u."Biography",
    p."PicturePath"
FROM "Users" as u 
INNER JOIN "Posts" as p ON u."ID" = p."UserID"
WHERE p."UserID" = 9;
```

I'm also trying to do the same thing but as a json

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user | [{"photo" : null, "username" : "username", "name" : "user", "bio" : null}, {"photo" : null, "username" : "username", "name" : "user", "bio" : null}]
pics | {https://gourmetdemexico.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/diferencia-entre-arte-y-cultura-taco-gringo-600x600.jpg,http://www.travelettes.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mystery2-600x600.jpg}
```

QUERY:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
    'photo', u."PhotoPath",
    'username', u."Username",
    'name', u."Name",
    'bio', u."Biografy"
)) as user,
array_agg(p."PicturePath") as pics
FROM "Users" as u
INNER JOIN "Posts" as p
ON u."ID" = p."UserID"
WHERE u."ID" = 9
GROUP BY p."UserID";
```

I know why but I don't know how to avoid it, can someone help me to get something like this:

```
user | {"photo" : null, "username" : "username", "name" : "user", "bio" : null}, 
pics | [https://gourmetdemexico.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/diferencia-entre-arte-y-cultura-taco-gringo-600x600.jpg,http://www.travelettes.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mystery2-600x600.jpg]
```

Comment: Those are not duplicates.  Each user can be associated with more than one post. That's all you're seeing.  You could try to use aggregation `GROUP BY` and `array_agg`, `string_agg` to combine post detail in one column of the result per user.

Comment: I know it's not a duplicate, when I inner those tables I get 2 results from that user because it has two rows in the posts, but I didn't know how to make the rows of the posts join with each user in such a way that it brings me only one user with their respective publications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this I resolve the issue:

```sql
WITH cte(j) AS (
    SELECT 
        jsonb_build_object(
            'photo', "PhotoPath",
            'username', "Username",
            'name', "Name",
            'bio', "Biography",
            'posts', array_agg(
                "Posts"."PicturePath"
            )
        )
        FROM "Users"
        INNER JOIN "Posts" ON "Posts"."UserID" = "Users"."ID"
        WHERE "Users"."ID" = @
        GROUP BY "Users"."ID"
)
SELECT json_agg(j) as user
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are poor. Why & how is this an answer? It's not clear in the question just what "the issue" is or what the desired result is supposed to be, and this answer doesn't say what it thinks those are either. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.